# Enabling MS Security Essentials blocks port web server

Tags: port, webserver, ms-security-essentials

I notice when I enable "real-time production" in MS Security Essentials that my web-service (on port 80) is blocked from outside my machine. I can still access it locally, even with my network IP.

Why is this? And is there any way I can prevent it from getting in the way of things using port 80?